# Representing the double factorial of LaguerreL[n, 1, x]/( (n + 1) LaguerreL[n, 0, x])

Tags: special-functions

I have calculations involving the following sum:

```
Sum[f[2n]!! Cos[2(n-l) Pi], {n, 1, ∞}, {l, 0, n - 1}]
```

where

```
f[2n]!! = f[0] f[2] f[4], ..., f[2n]
```

with f[0] = 1. In my case

```
f[n_] := LaguerreL[n, 1, x]/((n + 1) LaguerreL[n, 0, x])
```

I am having a lot of difficulty expressing the expression `f[n]!!` in Mathematica. I am looking for ideas on how to make the expression.

Comment: You need to plot the product of that function? $\prod^n_{i=1}f(2i)$?

Comment: yes, I need plot the function which contains  Laguerre polynomials written as the Eq. (1)

Comment: f[n] := 
 Module[{valor = 1}, 
  For[j = 0, j <= n, j++, 
   valor = valor LaguerreL[2 j, 1, 
      a^2]/((2 j + 1) LaguerreL[2 j, a^2])]; valor]

Comment: I tried with that but is not the solution

Comment: Does `p` have a particular value, like `Pi`?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `f[2n]!!` by `Product[f[2 m], {m, n}]`. To verify,

```
Product[g[2 m], {m, 6}]
(* g[2] g[4] g[6] g[8] g[10] g[12] *)
```

as desired. However, it is not clear that Mathematica can perform the resulting double `Sum`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a little by noting that

```
n==Sum[ Cos[2 (n - l) π], {l, 0, n - 1}] // FullSimplify

(* True  *)
```

So the problem becomes a single sum

```
Sum[n Product[f[2 m], {m,1,n}] , {n, 1, ∞}]
```

or after some more manipulation

```
Sum[(n /(2 n + 1)!!) Product[LaguerreL[2 m, 1, x]/( LaguerreL[2 m, 0, x]), {m, 1, n}], 
    {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

The leading `(n /(2 n + 1)!!)` converges extremely fast in `n`, allowing you to truncate the infinite sum to some reasonable number, thus creating a function in `x`.